# Seeking advice to optimize the following code chunk. (I need to avoid the IF ELSES)

Tags: php, optimization

I have a JSON file with around 30 sub sections. Each subsection will be different. I wanted to convert the data inside it into a format i wanted. The code works fine. But i feel its not optimized 100%.

`Client1Insurance, Client2Insurance, ClientFInsurance, FamilyInsurance, Client1Pension, Client2Pension, ClientFPension, FamilyPension`.

Above is an example of how this JSON would look like. All above are arrays which have sub arrays inside them. There are around 30 arrays like this.

```
foreach ($json as $item) {
 if (strpos($crmMapKey, "Insurance")) {
     $returnArray[] = $this->handleInsurance($item);
 } elseif (strpos($crmMapKey, "Pension")) {
    $returnArray[] = $this->handlePension($item);
 } ... continues the comparison till the json ends
}
```

I need a way to avoid this long if else comparions which I am not proud of. Will someone be able to suggest a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Cant use a switch here.  
```Client1Insurance, Client2Insurance, ClientFInsurance, FamilyInsurance```
will have 4 cases. But in the current code i have, it will have only one 

```strpos($crmMapKey, "Insurance")``` - This avoids the 4 cases.

@AbraCadaver

Comment: `switch(true)` then cases are your `strpos`, so maybe not the best but you can use it.

Comment: Any other options? @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are named the same as you show in your code, something containing `Insurance` will call `handleInsurance`, etc. then just get the term and use it in the method call:

```
preg_match('/Insurance|Pension/', $crmMapKey, $match);
$returnArray[] = $this->{'handle'.$match[0]}($item);
```

If not then you can use a lookup array:

```
$lookup = ['Insurance' => 'doSomething', 'Pension' => 'doAnotherThing'];
preg_match('/Insurance|Pension/', $crmMapKey, $match);
$returnArray[] = $this->{'handle'.$lookup[$match[0]]}($item);
```

Or use the keys in the pattern so you only have to modify the array:

```
preg_match('/'.implode('|', array_keys($lookup)).'/', $crmMapKey, $match);
```

The `switch` I mentioned in a comment might not be the best but works:

```
switch(true) {
    case strpos($crmMapKey, "Insurance") !== false;
        $returnArray[] = $this->handleInsurance($item);
        break;

    case strpos($crmMapKey, "Pension") !== false;
        $returnArray[] = $this->handlePension($item);
        break;

    //etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to call variable based functions.

```
foreach ($json as $item) {
    $returnArray[] = $crmMapKey($item);
}

function Client1Insurance($item) {
    // Do something in here.
    return $array;
}

function Client2Insurance($item) {
    // Do something in here.
    return $array;
}
```

Much more elegant way of doing things I feel.